# Fork Rust Clippy and run built executable on other project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-clippy

I altered the linting messages in Clippy by forking the Clippy repo and changing for example "clippy_lints/no_panics.rs" to alter the message shown when clippy is not told what to do in the presence of panicking code. *(my real use case requires more, but it also needs at least what I described now)*

- I forked the Clippy repo to a folder called `clippy-clone`.
- I run `cargo build` which creates two binaries `cargo-clippy.exe` and `clippy-driver.exe`.

Now running this `cargo-clippy` (with `target\debug\cargo-clippy`) in the forked clippy folder seems to work as intended: it shows my changed lint message.

Now I want to use my own clippy version on some other folder.

- I traverse to that folder (sibling of the clippy clone)
- I run `..\clippy-clone\target\debug\cargo-clippy`

It errors and gives:

```
PS C:\Users\sibling-dir> ..\clippy-clone\target\debug\cargo-clippy    
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\clippy-clone\target\debug\clippy-driver.exe rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=cfg` (exit code: 0xc0000135, STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND)
```

So how do I built this fork properly and run it as a standalone application from any cargo project folder on my pc? I'm assuming it has something to do with other files (besides `cargo-clippy.exe`) not being present, but for example the real clippy can also be run from every folder, I want this same behaviour.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/clippy/development/basics.html#install-from-source

Comment: @PitaJ that seems interesting and useful already, thank you. However, I would want to be able to run it as a differently named program later on, and also still be able to use clippy. This approach seems to replace the real clippy in the toolchain.